# pep8 compliant deep dictionary access

Tags: python, pep8

What is the pep8 compliant way to do deep dictionary access?

```
dct = {
    'long_key_name_one': {
        'long_key_name_two': {
            'long_key_name_three': {
                'long_key_name_four': {
                    'long_key_name_five': 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

E501 line too long (118 > 80 characters)

```
print dct['long_key_name_one']['long_key_name_two']['long_key_name_three']['long_key_name_four']['long_key_name_five']
```

E211 whitespace before '['

```
print dct['long_key_name_one']['long_key_name_two']\
    ['long_key_name_three']['long_key_name_four']['long_key_name_five']
```

E124 closing bracket does not match visual indentation

```
print dct['long_key_name_one']['long_key_name_two'
    ]['long_key_name_three']['long_key_name_four']['long_key_name_five']
```

This passes pep8 but seems less than ideal

```
print dct['long_key_name_one']['long_key_name_two'][
    'long_key_name_three'
]['long_key_name_four']['long_key_name_five']
```

Is there a way to break up the line so that it looks nice and is pep8 compliant?

Comment: if the keys are already in a list and you know that the value exists then you could: `value = reduce(dict.get, keys, dct)`.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps not the best way, but it works:

```
a = dct['long_key_name_one']['long_key_name_two']
b = a['long_key_name_three']['long_key_name_four']['long_key_name_five']
```

But this also works, which is the suggested method:

```
print (dct['long_key_name_one']['long_key_name_two']
       ['long_key_name_three']['long_key_name_four']
       ['long_key_name_five'])
```

Comment: I think the first way is the best option. Except that really, the best option is to design your data structures better so you don't run into this in the first place. There aren't that many cases where you've got a tree of objects 5 levels deep where none of the intermediate levels are useful on their own—and, if you _do_ have such a case, you're probably better off using a tree iterator or DOM-style searches than this kind of access.

Comment: The first way doesn't help you if you need to set a value.

Comment: @tponthieux: sure it does. `a` is just a name for the internal dictionary in `dct`. `a[k] = v` is equivalent to `dct['long_key_name_one']['long_key_name_two'][k] = v` in this case.

Comment: Ah, you're right: `id(dct['long_key_name_one']['long_key_name_two']) == id(a)`

Answer (score 4):

If you use it inside a function (and you could use print() as a function since 2.7 afaik)

You could just use implicit concatenation within a parentheses

```
print(dct['long_key_name_one']
         ['long_key_name_two']
         ['long_key_name_three']
         ['long_key_name_four']
         ['long_key_name_five'])
```