# How to respect PEP8 when accessing multiple nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, pep8

I have a line of code like this:

```
mydict['description_long'] = another_dict['key1'][0]['a_really_long_key']['another_long_key']['another_long_key3']['another_long_key4']['another_long_key5']
```

How do I format it so it adheres to the PEP8 guidelines?

Comment: Split it into two using an intermediate variable?

Comment: Have you tried the [PEP8 Checker](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) to see if that's a legal line? I'm sure it breaks the line length rule, but it might tell you what to do

Comment: wow thats pretty nested!! It's a bit of an eye bleed, can't you break it down and hide some of the levels of indirection behind meaningfully named function calls? That would get rid of the need produce such long lines.

Comment: [PEP8 compliant deep dictionary access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204076/pep8-compliant-deep-dictionary-access) has a few answers, although not a definitive one (so I don't think it's a good candidate for a dupe)

Comment: @SterlingArcher I think that's the point of the question, although, it isn't explicit.

Comment: PEP8 is trying to tell you that having such a structure is maybe not a very nice thing.

Answer (score 11):

The only relevant part of PEP8's style guidelines here is line length. Just break up the `dict` keys into their own separate lines. This makes the code way easier to read as well.

```
mydict['description_long'] = (another_dict['key1']
                                          [0]
                                          ['a_really_long_key']
                                          [etc.])
```

Comment: This does not pass a PEP8 check either, but I would consider this better than the above. "[Whitespace] Immediately before the open parenthesis that starts an indexing or slicing: Yes: `dct['key'] = lst[index]`  No:  `dct ['key'] = lst [index]`"

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd do something like this, add parens to go over multiple lines:

```
mydict['description_long'] = (
    another_dict['key1'][0]['a_really_long_key']['another_long_key']
    ['another_long_key3']['another_long_key4']['another_long_key5'])
```

Though it'd be better not to have such a deep structure in the first place, or to split up the lookup into several, if you can give those good names:

```
item = another_dict['key1'][0]['a_really_long_key']
part_name = item['another_long_key']['another_long_key3']
detail = part_name['another_long_key4']['another_long_key5']
```

At least that way the deep structure is documented a little.

Comment: really agree with that second part, instead of fumbling around with breaking it up into multiple lines

Answer (score 1):

each `[` is a bracket. So it nominally just like nesting parenthesis:

```
mydict['description_long'] = another_dict['key1'][0][
    'a_really_long_key']['another_long_key'][
        'another_long_key3']['another_long_key4'][
            'another_long_key4']
```

A more generic way might be to just do some metaprogramming and use a series of list comprehensions or iteration to expand child datastructures. For example, your child node can be found by following a path represented by the list:

```
keypath = ['key1', 0, 'a_really_long_key', 'another_long_key', 
           'another_long_key3','another_long_key4',
           'another_long_key4']
```

so you reference your final node by something like:

```
def resolve_child(root, path):
    for e in path:
        child = root[e]
        root = child
    return child

mydict['description_long'] = resolve_path(another_dict, keypath)
```

Or if you want to be all functional (Note that `reduce()` is moved to `functools` in Py3K):

```
mydict['description_long'] = reduce(lambda p,c: p[c], keypath, another_dict)
```

It is usually rare that you have to explicitly reference a deeply nested structure like that; usually the structure is being instantiated by some function, like json.parse or lxml.objectify

Comment: Your first grouping I would say is worse than just throwing it all on one line.

Comment: Note sure if it passes PEP 8 though? I mean the closing bracket /does/ "match" the visual indentation in this case...

Comment: Realistically, I think PEP 8 is intentionally a **guideline**. There are reasonable exceptions to most rules. I relatively regularly, intentionally violate PEP8 because it makes the code more readable... and PyCharm complains and I ignore it. Because at the end of the day, another dev is going to be the one who has to figure it out, and I'll break guidelines where they detract from the overall readability.

Comment: Note that _all_ of these methods make it harder to figure out what's actually happening. That's not the point of PEP8.